# WebLogic - Identifying multiple deployments of the same ear

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, weblogic

I have WebLogic 11g and  12c, and  I have an ear file.  Now I want to deploy multiple copies of that same ear on the same webLogic instance, under different names.  I would like some java code tell me in which of these copies I am currently executing code.

I need this information for multiple purposes:

- For a status screen, to show my identity for troubleshooting purposes
- For determining which configuration info to read

etc...

I'd prefer a solution without requiring a specific deployment plan.

Answer (score 0):

Except using `HttpServletRequest#getContextPath()` i don't see.
Maybe some java system property ? I know there is a trick in Spring to get this, have a look to Spring `WebAppRootListener` implementation, you may find your happiness there.

Comment: No spring in this application, and getContextPath works in the web layer but not in the ejb layer :-(

Comment: Indeed. ejb equivalent is `@Resource
private void setSessionContext(SessionContext sctx)` but you don't have path notion